# Process TCP Socket data read in different thread

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, winsock

I are developing a program to integrate with a device which sends data over TCP channel every 70 ms.

I am using Socket.BeginReceive and Socket.EndReceive methods to read the data. The logic is depicted in following pseudo code

```
private void OnReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var rcvdDataLength = m_tcpSocket.EndReceive(ar);
    Array.Copy(m_tempRecvBuffer, 0, m_mainBuffer, m_mainBufferDataIndex, rcvdDataLength);
    if (CheckIfValidHeaderAndBodyReceived())
    {
        var actualData = new byte[headerLen + BodyLen];
        Array.Copy(m_mainBuffer, m_dataIndex, actualData, 0, headerLen + BodyLen);
        Process(actualData);
    }
    m_tcpSocket.BeginReceive(m_tempRecvBuffer, 0, m_tempRecvBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
        OnReceived, null);
}
```

Process function depicted in the above code is responsible for implementing the business logic. Process function currently takes around 300 ms.

So the consumer (which takes 300 ms) is slower than producer (which publishes data every 70 ms). Do I need to run this Process function asynchronously to avoid the delay? Or [flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control) aspect of TCP layer take care of this?

Comment: It seems like you're going to have to consider discarding some messages if consuming takes ~3 times longer than the rate at which the messages are received. Simply moving the processing to a different thread would result in an ever increasing number of threads until resources are exhausted unless I'm missing something.

Comment: If you can parallelize the consumers (see `BlockingCollection<T>`) such that you're able to consume data at a fast enough rate (e.g. 5 consuming threads working concurrently which can process the incoming data at an average net rate of 60 ms per data unit), that could work. On the other hand, if the consuming endpoint does not start a new read operation until the current data unit has been processed, then yes...the TCP protocol will "handle" things locally. However, the remote endpoint could then wind up exhausting its resources, depending on its own implementation.

Comment: Bottom line: lots of different outcomes are possible, and lots of different solutions might be appropriate, and there's not enough information in your post for anyone to provide a good answer about either.

Comment: What do you ***want*** to happen?

Comment: @itsme86 When I meant asynchronous, I meant to write the data to be processed to a queue and then consume it from another single thread.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Your suggestion is what I was thinking of. But I can only one thread to read since the order of messages is important (am I missing something?).

Comment: Don't confuse reading data from the socket with processing that data elsewhere.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Could you give more inputs on how remote endpoint wind up exhausting its resources? Do you mean the memory used by TCP/IP stack?

Comment: Like I said, it depends on how the remote endpoint is implemented. But, if it is generating data every 70 ms and unconditionally attempts to transmit that data to your client, and the client is only receiving each unit of data every 300 ms, then the data being transmitted will be queued at the server and will eventually consume the server's memory. Some server implementations detect the condition of an unresponsive/too-slow client and will either discard data or drop the client entirely. Others may not.

Comment: Thank you. How would the server implementation detect the condition? Say, if I am writing the server, how would I generally do it? Is it from the time it took to 'Write' to the network stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to run this Process function asynchronously to avoid the delay?

This depends on your application and ultimately your own decision of priorities. Strictly speaking, no you don't *need* to do anything asynchronously, but it can be a good thing to do.

The approach I usually use and recommend is a thread dedicated to the interface that interacts with the rest of the application through a queue. As the communication thread receives messages, it locks a queue and pushes them in. When the main application is ready to consume that data, it locks that queue and dequeues as much as it needs to. It's a simple, robust, and reliable mechanism. Going to your pseudocode:

```
private void OnReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var rcvdDataLength = m_tcpSocket.EndReceive(ar);
    Array.Copy(m_tempRecvBuffer, 0, m_mainBuffer, m_mainBufferDataIndex, rcvdDataLength);
    if (CheckIfValidHeaderAndBodyReceived())
    {
        var actualData = new byte[headerLen + BodyLen];
        Array.Copy(m_mainBuffer, m_dataIndex, actualData, 0, headerLen + BodyLen);
        lock(messageQueue)
        {
           messageQueue.Enqueue(actualData);
        }
    }
    m_tcpSocket.BeginReceive(m_tempRecvBuffer, 0, m_tempRecvBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
        OnReceived, null);
}
```

And then somewhere in your application:

```
void ProcessQueue()
{
   Queue<byte[]> tempQueue = new Queue<byte[]>();
   lock(messageQueue)
   {
      // Drain the queue so we can release the lock ASAP
      while(messageQueue.Count > 0)
      {
         tempQueue.Enqueue(messageQueue.Dequeue());
      }
   }
   while(tempQueue.Count > 0)
   {
      Process(tempQueue.Dequeue());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort to answer. I will try this and get back to you

Comment: Your solution is working like a charm. Could you suggest how to run ProcessQueue? I am actually calling it in an infinite while loop in its own dedicated thread. Or should I invoke ProcessQueue in a timer with a very short time interval (say 30ms)?

Comment: That's another architectural question and depends on your application's goals and existing structure. You mentioned the Consumer takes 300ms, so I'd assume the Consumer would invoke ProcessQueue when it is ready.

Comment: FWIW, I used this approach for TCP for the first time this week. I've traditionally used this queue approach for serial and USB communications. I have a BackgroundWorker managing a TcpListener, receiving and decoding messages, and putting valid messages on a queue. Another BackgroundWorker monitors the queue and performs some slow cryptographic processing on the messages before putting them into a different IEnumerable. There's overhead, of course, but it ensures slow processes like RSA decryption don't block the network interface or GUI.